# Appending new inputs with JS wipes previous ones

Tags: javascript, html, html-input

So I have this code,

```js
spellNumber = 0

function createSpell() {
  document.getElementById("spells").innerHTML +=
    '<p><input type="text"></p><br />'
  spellNumber += 1;
  spellsActive = true
}
```

```html
<a onClick="createSpell()" class="spellButton" style="background-color:#717171">Add a Spell</a>
<div id="spells"></div>
```

but whenever I try to add another input by clicking the button, it wipes any previous ones. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: innerHTML is bad way to add more HTML content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenating with existing `.innerHTML` will mean that only the *HTML string* of previous elements is retained - your `input`s don't have a `.value` *attribute*, so it appears that the values get lost. (what's actually happening is that the element gets destroyed, then re-created with the new full HTML string.)

Instead of concatenating with the existing `innerHTML`, use `createElement` instead, so as not to corrupt what exists in the container already:

```js
let spellNumber = 0;
const spells = document.getElementById("spells")

function createSpell() {
  const p = spells.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
  const input  = p.appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
  spells.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
  spellNumber += 1;
  spellsActive = true
}
```

```html
<a onClick="createSpell()" class="spellButton" style="background-color:#717171">Add a Spell</a>
<div id="spells"></div>
```

Another option would be to use `insertAdjacentHTML`, which, like `appendChild`, will not corrupt existing elements:

```js
let spellNumber = 0;
const spells = document.getElementById("spells")

function createSpell() {
  spells.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p><input type="text"></input></p></br>');
  spellNumber += 1;
  spellsActive = true
}
```

```html
<a onClick="createSpell()" class="spellButton" style="background-color:#717171">Add a Spell</a>
<div id="spells"></div>
```